# how to save images from a multiple input in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

That is in templates, I have the following code. the file input has a multiple attribute in the end so that I can select multiple images.

```
<form method='POST' action="{% url 'method' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="file" name="img" multiple />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
   <br />
```

Then I am having trouble to save the image to my model. I tried to print request.FILES, and I got this

```
<MultiValueDict: {'img': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: 1.jpg (image/jpeg)>, 
<InMemoryUploadedFile: 2.jpg (image/jpeg)>, <InMemoryUploadedFile: 3.jpg 
(image/jpeg)>]}>
```

There are 3 items in 'img', I also used request.FILES.getlist('img'), doesn't really work out. How am I suppose to access the content in the 'img' like accessing several individual request.FILES. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I cannot believe I solved the problem 10mins after I posted it. The key is still
request.FILES.getlist('img'), but make sure you don't use chunks() later, so if you want save the image, save it directly like

```
for image in request.FILES.getlist('img'):
   xxxx.image = image
   xxx.save()
```

That's it. don't use any chunks() methods.